# remove values on the basis of another column

Tags: r

i have two columns in data frame both have values like one have total score and one have expected score. now i want to values from expected score columns where expected score is greater that total score.

```
df <- data.frame(tota_score=c(4.5,12.2,4.6,9.2,12.2,36.4,4.5,12.2,4.6,9.2,12.2,36.4),
                 expected_score=c(4.5,12.1,NA,10,12.2,NA,5,12.5,NA,9.2,16,NA),
                 Region1=c("All region",NA,NA,"All region","All region",NA,"All region",NA,NA,"All region","All region",NA),
                 Region2=c("EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST",NA,"EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST",NA),
                 Region3=c("West",NA,"West","West","West","West","West",NA,"West","West","West","West"))
```

Comment: Note that your `total_score` column has a typo as `tota_score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first option that uses `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(expected_score = ifelse(expected_score > total_score, 
                                   NA, expected_score))
```

```
   total_score expected_score    Region1 Region2 Region3
1          4.5            4.5 All region    EAST    West
2         12.2           12.1       <NA>    EAST    <NA>
3          4.6             NA       <NA>    EAST    West
4          9.2             NA All region    EAST    West
5         12.2           12.2 All region    EAST    West
6         36.4             NA       <NA>    <NA>    West
7          4.5             NA All region    EAST    West
8         12.2             NA       <NA>    EAST    <NA>
9          4.6             NA       <NA>    EAST    West
10         9.2            9.2 All region    EAST    West
11        12.2             NA All region    EAST    West
12        36.4             NA       <NA>    <NA>    West
```

Using `data.table` you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[expected_score > total_score, expected_score  := NA]
```

On a large `data.frame`, the latter option using `data.table` should be much faster.

Comment: if the total_score is blank and expected score is having value  then i wanted to ignore that condition

Comment: Is this not what occurs now? Also, what does the yellow in your image mean?

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
df[which(df[!is.na(df$expected_score),2] > df[!is.na(df$expected_score),1]),]
```

#here 2 is your expected score and 1 is your total score